# Is there any for PSFTP on Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, psftp

May I ask if anyone have succeeded in coding a dos batch that uses PSFTP and scheduled it in Windows Task Scheduler? or have encountered problem doing it?

I initially coded DOS batch (using FTP) and scheduled its run with Windows Task Scheduler. And this one works fine even up to now.

Our new server is configured in our network security policy only allowing secured FTP. So I am forced to develop a code that uses PSFTP. Some minor adjustment done to fit on the switches of PSFTP. Running it manually from commandline or double-click from Windows Explorer works fine. But when I schedule its run in Windows Task Scheduler, it reports status of running even after a long time (20 mins.)...seems it gets stuck at the first PSFTP execution. Here's my DOS batch code for reference

---

```
set home=C:\mydirectory
cd %home%
rem 
rem 
set folder=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set dira=%home%\%folder%
set svrdir = %dira%/server1
set ffddir = %dira%/ffdc
set mysvr=xx.xx.xx.xx
set usr=zzzzzzzz
set pword=pppppp
set lg=ftp2.log


if not exist %dira% mkdir %folder%
cd %dira%


%home%\psftp -b %home%\codeS.ftp %usr%@%mysvr% -pw %pword%>>%lg%
%home%\psftp -b %home%\codeF.ftp %usr%@%mysvr% -pw %pword%>>%lg%

if not exist %dira%\server1 mkdir server1
if not exist %dira%\ffdc mkdir ffdc


copy /Y SystemOut_* server1\ >>%lg%
copy /Y server1_*.txt  ffdc\ >>%lg%

del /Q .\*.*
```

---

Comment: I'm using curl for this. Works fine with SFTP and windows scheduler.

Comment: Remove the spaces in your `SET` commands.

Comment: In addition to Squashman's comment, use backslashes instead of forward slashes for svrdir and ffddir